# Getting the line number of the line that has the caret in uitextview

Tags: ios, uitextview

Is it possible to get the line number of the currently editing line of a UITextView.

- The lines may be broken up automatically.
- The user may enter a new line character

I have seen a lot of issues where people calculate the number of rows in a textview but none of them calculate number of rows before caret.

To get the number of lines in total something like this can be used:

```
CGFloat numLines = self.contentSize.height/self.font.lineHeight;
NSLog(@"Total lines: %f", numLines);
```

**But if i tap in the middle of the text I want to get the line number of the
line I am activating for editing.**

I also know that we can get the position of the caret in terms of x and y coordinates like soo:

```
CGPoint cursorPosition = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
NSLog(@"cursor start: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cursorPosition));
```

Any clever ideas?

Comment: Get the text up to the cursor. Calculate that bounding rect of that text based on the font and width. That will give you the text's height.

Answer (score 1):

How about `selectedTextRange`? If its length is 0, you are looking at the caret location. Once you have that you can `enumerateLines…` until you find the range containing caret location.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you want this?

```
int currentLine = (int)(cursorPosition.y / self.font.lineHeight);
```

You might need a +1 in there too, to account for the caretRect being right at the top of the line, you'll have to try it.

Comment: What if a line is longer than the Text View's width and split over multiple lines?